# Facebook Unity SDK 5.0.4 iOS feed callbacks are missing post id

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Here is a screenshot from Xcode in debug mode running my app on iOS, right after posting a feed: http://screencast.com/t/ium048TZi9

The postId is missing from the dictionary. The feed post *is* working, as I see the post on my FB wall. So, it's just the iOS callback not getting the post id.

On Android this is working as intended. On the previous version of the SDK it was also broken.

Here is my c# code that generates the feed:

```
// the ID of the wall to post to facebook.  Leave blank for logged in user
string FeedToId = "";
// The URL to which this post should link.  Default: The base URL of the posting application, as configured in the Developer App
string FeedLink = "http://apps.facebook.com/slotsvacation-foxcub/?action=feed&postGuid=" + _fbPost.postGuid.Base64Encode();
// The name of the story, shown at the top and rendered as a hyperlink with href set to link.  Default: The app name, as configured in the Developer App
string FeedLinkName = "Slots Vacation";
// A short description, rendered below linkName in the story.  Default: The app base URL
string FeedLinkCaption = "Share the Loot!";
// A longer description, rendered as the main body of the story.
string FeedLinkDescription = string.Format("Click this to get {0} {1}.", SharePrizeAmount(_lastPrize.value, prizeType), TreasurePrize.GetNameForPrize(prizeType));
// The URL of a picture, in PNG of JPEG format, to display beside the story; see the Feed Dialog documentation for details.
string FeedPicture = "http://slots-vacation.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/facebook/feeds/FBfeed_bonus_tropical.png";
// The URL of audio or video content to display beside the story; see Feed Gaming documentation for details
string FeedMediaSource = "";
// The text of the action link; see actionLink, below
string FeedActionName = "";
// A link rendered at the bottom of the story which can optionally have a different target than the main story link; see documentation
string FeedActionLink = "";
// A name for the category of feed post, used in Facebook Insights to help you measure the performance of different types of post
string FeedReference = "P_W_Prize";     

Dictionary<string, string[]> feedProperties = null;

FB.Feed(
    toId: FeedToId,
    link: FeedLink,
    linkName: FeedLinkName,
    linkCaption: FeedLinkCaption,
    linkDescription: FeedLinkDescription,
    picture: FeedPicture,
    mediaSource: FeedMediaSource,
    actionName: FeedActionName,
    actionLink: FeedActionLink,
    reference: FeedReference,
    properties: feedProperties,
    callback: FeedCallback
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a story is posted via the facebook ios app, no post id will be returned unless you have the  publish_actions permission.

Comment: Why is there a disconnect between being able to post a feed and getting the post id? Seems like those would be the same permission.


Also why is it different on Android? I'm not asking for publish_actions on either.

Comment: "Note, you do not need to request the publish_actions permission in order to use the Feed Dialog, the Requests Dialog or the Send Dialog."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

I guess that makes sense.